# Finding the number of columns of a dataset that are of numeric type

Tags: r

I have a data frame `df` containing columns of different class. I want to get the number of columns that are of numeric type. I tried `which(df$(class(df[,i] == "numeric")))`, `ncol(df[,class(df[,i])!="factor"))`, both of which resulted in error messages.

Can you help me out ? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
df <- data.frame( a = letters[1:10], b = 1:10, c = 11:20 )
sum( lapply( df, is.numeric ) == TRUE )
```

Comment: A slightly more refined option could be `sum(sapply(df, is.numeric))`.

Comment: darn.. I *always* forget **s**apply... is indeed the better option here

Comment: Thanks. It worked perfectly. Why were my attempts wrong ?

Comment: A slightly slightly more refined option of @tmfmnk suggestion would by `sum(vapply(df, function(x) is.numeric(x), logical(1)))`, right? I make this suggestion since with `vapply` you can control the output. `sapply` tries to simplify the result, so it would be optimal to use `vapply` here given its control over the output?

Answer (score 1):

An option with `select`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
    select(where(is.numeric)) %>%
    ncol
```